# Delve does not work always with LiteIDE

Tags: go, liteide, delve

I am new to go language and for development purpose using LITEIDE with delve as debugger to debug my go code .

I have observed that sometimes I can debug well in LITEIDE with breakpoints being hit and I can use it properly . But sometimes it just doesnt work at all .

When it DOES NOT WORK i see messages like these in console

```
(dlv) Process restarted with PID 29878
(dlv) (dlv) (dlv) Breakpoint bk145085445 set at 0x206d for main.main() ./httpServer.go:15
(dlv) Breakpoint bk83028073 set at 0xd3546 for usagereports/requestHandlers.KeyHandler() ./requestHandlers/customerKeyHandler.go:39
(dlv) Breakpoint bk83028064 set at 0xd2e69 for usagereports/requestHandlers.KeyHandler() ./requestHandlers/customerKeyHandler.go:30
(dlv) Breakpoint bk83028049 set at 0xd2bc8 for usagereports/requestHandlers.KeyHandler() ./requestHandlers/customerKeyHandler.go:21
(dlv) Breakpoint 5 set at 0x2058 for main.main() ./httpServer.go:12
(dlv)
```

Now If I type next (to go to next line) or continue (for it to stop at next breakpoint) nothing happens . But the program has not hanged and I can see it getting executed (through log messages or see desired output/errors on screen) which means that LITEIDE is not working properly.

Can anyone guide here who uses LITEIDE with Delve and faced this problem

Comment: Does the exact same input work directly in delve?

Comment: I've experienced the same behavior.  Everything seems to work directly in delve.  In the cases that I've looked into, it seems to have something to do with debugging within a GoRoutine.

Comment: I've not had good luck with the debugger either, to the point where I barely use it.  I've been relying on log.Println()

Comment: I havent used delve directly , but tier1 answer is encouraging me to look into it.

Comment: Apparently , it doesn't seem to work even directly in delve making me think if  its worth investing time into this.